# Is there a way to show the Keyboard Key representation of the XBox buttons on the pc version of The Last Remnant?

Tags: the-last-remnant

I have started the Last Remnant recently, really love the game, but I have some issues remembering which keys I assigned to which XBox key representation (that sucked to explain it)

Instead of having the game show [press A] [B] [X] [Y]  [RB] < ???  , can I have the game in some way show [spacebar] [up arrow] [del] (keyboard or mouse buttons)  (as example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible

> Keyboard prompts: If you are playing with keyboard/mouse, you're going to want to tell the game to pompt you with keys instead of XBox gamepad buttons. Go to the main menu, pick options, go over to the gamepad section of the options, and there will be an option right at the top saying "Key Signal Display". Select it, press space, and select the Keyboard option.

Source: [Steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/23310/discussions/0/882959527677194857/)

Comment: Love you longtime. thanks.

I think I was on that post (I was on A steam community post), but I was like "wall of text, at work, not reading THAT"

Launched game during lunchbreak, set the option, checked it out, seems to work.

Comment: No problem. Word of advice - read it. The game is freaking brutal. It has hidden stuff all over the place and things that can literally ruin a playthrough. This is not your ordinary RPG.

Comment: That's what gives the game a multiple playthrough quality :)